# Plesk remove hosting type `Website hosting` from service plan

Tags: centos, hosting, plesk, plesk-onyx

I am using Plesk Onyx Web Host Edition 17.5.3 + CentOS 7.

I want to create a `Service plan` where the `Customer` can change the `Hosting type` from `No webhosting`to `forwarding` and back, while LACKING the option to change it to `Website hosting`.

How do I remove the `Hosting type` `Website hosting` from a `Service plan`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature in Plesk at the moment. The only option is to set `No hosting`, but then it will be impossible to switch to `Forwarding` as well.

You can always suggest new functionality via the following link - https://plesk.uservoice.com/forums/184549-feature-suggestions Describe your use case there.